# joining two json object with array object in it

Tags: javascript, json

**response is stored in data1**

```
ad.display(sha.c function(data1) {
                dataFirst(data1);

            });
```

**response is stored in data2**

```
  ad.display(sha.c, function(data2) {
                dataSecond(data2);
                superDisplay(concatData);
            });

function dataFirst(data1){
    return data1;
}
function dataSecond(data2){
    return data2;
}
function concatData(data1,data2){
    return dataFirst.concat(dataSecond);
}
```

response objects data1 and data2 are json which looks like

```
        data1={errors: null, rowdata: Array[4], state: Object}
        data2={errors: null, rowdata: Array[9], state: Object}
```

i want to merge them and create a single json object. The resultant json should have all the values from data2 and the values from data1 which is not present in data2.

so concatData json should be like this

```
concatData={errors: null, rowdata: Array[13], state: Object}
```

this is the expected result which i am not getting

**rowdata should contain value from both data1 and data2**

JavaScript answer are most welcomed

Comment: Would you like to share what you have experimented so far ?

Comment: i tried concat function

Comment: There's no JSON in your question. Those are just objects.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ShashankKumar , It would be great if you share that attempt and would allow many of us out here to correct where you went wrong :-)

Comment: What is the property key (`state.someProperty`? `rowdata[i]`? etc.) which you desire to group by? Which **value** is to be added from `data1` if not persent in `data2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the example code [from here](http://gomakethings.com/vanilla-javascript-version-of-jquery-extend/) and modified it to merge arrays. A [fiddle is available here](https://jsfiddle.net/kxyamfL4/) (open the inspector to see the logs).

```
var extend = function () {
    var extended = {}, deep = false, i = 0, length = arguments.length;

    // Check if a deep merge
    if ( Object.prototype.toString.call( arguments[0] ) === '[object Boolean]' ) {
        deep = arguments[0];
        i++;
    }

    // Merge the object into the extended object
    var merge = function (obj) {
        for ( var prop in obj ) {
            if ( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( obj, prop ) ) {
                // If deep merge and property is an object, merge properties
                if ( deep && Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Object]' ) {
                    extended[prop] = extend( true, extended[prop], obj[prop] );
                } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Array]') {
                    if (extended[prop] && Object.prototype.toString.call(extended[prop]) === '[object Array]') {
                    extended[prop] = extended[prop].concat(obj[prop]);
                  } else if (!extended[prop]) {
                    extended[prop] = obj[prop];
                  }
                } else {
                    extended[prop] = obj[prop];
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Loop through each object and conduct a merge
    for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
        var obj = arguments[i];
        merge(obj);
    }

    return extended;

};

var item1 = { name: 'Frank', age: 42, pets: ['cat', 'dog']};
var item2 = { name: 'Jane', pets: ['fish']};
var item3 = extend(true, item1, item2);
window.console.log(item3);
```

It should get you on the path to where you want to be. Personally I feel it would need more work to be on par with jQuery's extend.